# Unexpected labeled statement - React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a react native app and have a component that only return values, but it give me an error `Unexpected labeled statement` which I think is the reason my app crashes when I run `npx react-native start`.

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

export default function () {
  MAX_WIDTH: Dimensions.get('screen').width;
  MAX_HEIGHT: Dimensions.get('screen').height;
  GAP_SIZE: 300;
}
```

Comment: `export default function App() {}` functions component must has a name. Also, components must return either JSX or null. If this solves the problem tell me to write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is return some data then what you can do is create an object, assign the values to it and export it as the default like this:

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const Data = {
    MAX_WIDTH: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    MAX_HEIGHT: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
    GAP_SIZE: 300,
}

export default Data;
```